# Altair Y-Axis Label Left-Alignment & Spacing Edits Possible?

Tags: label, alignment, spacing, altair

I'm trying to recreate this chart in Altair but can't figure out how to make a few minor edits: https://datawrapper.dwcdn.net/E0jaK/1/

Here's my current progress: https://i.stack.imgur.com/NMkmO.jpg

The three edits I'm trying to figure out are:

- How to left-align y-axis labels
- How to add spacing between the labels and the y-axis
- How to move bar number labels to the base of the bars instead of the ends

Any insight on how to implement these edits would be great.

Here's the raw data:

```
Crime,Count
Larceny/Theft,739
Assault,177
Burglary/Breaking & Entering,133
Destruction of Property/Vandalism,128
Drugs,107
Motor Vehicle Theft,95
Fraud,71
Sex Offenses,57
Suspicious Activity,45
Trespassing,23
Family Offenses,22
Weapons Violations,21
```

This is the theme I used:

```
def chart_theme():
    font = "Calibri"
    return {
        "width": 700,
        "height": 300,
        "background": "white",
        "config": {
            "title": {
                "fontSize": 20,
                "anchor": "start" 
            },
            "axisY": {
                "labelFont": font,
                "labelFontSize": 13,
                "labelLimit":200,
                "ticks": False, 
                "titleFont": font,
                "titleFontSize": 12,
                "titleAlign":"right",
                "titleAngle": 0, 
                "titleY": -10, 
                "titleX": 25, 
            },
            "view":{"stroke": "transparent",
            },
}
    }
```

And here's the chart code:

```
base = alt.Chart(df, title='San Francisco Crime (11/05 - 11/11)').encode(
    x=alt.X('Count', axis=None),
    y=alt.Y('Crime', title='Crimes reported to SFPD, by top complaint', 
    sort=list(df.Crime.values)))

bars = base.mark_bar(size=22).encode(color=alt.condition(
    alt.datum.Count > 700,
    alt.value('#e17700'),
    alt.value('#00648e')))

text = base.mark_text(
    color='white',
    align='right',
    size=12,
    dx=-3
).encode(
    text='Count')

chart = bars + text
chart
```

Any guidance/suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You may want to break this question up into different posts, one for each specific question. People are more likely to answer a post that has a short, direct, answer.

Comment: That's a good point, @max . I'll keep that in mind next time.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

How about something like this

```py
import pandas as pd
import altair as alt

data = {'Larceny/Theft':739,
'Assault':177,
'Burglary/Breaking & Entering':133,
'Destruction of Property/Vandalism':128,
'Drugs':107,
'Motor Vehicle Theft':95,
'Fraud':71,
'Sex Offenses':57,
'Suspicious Activity':45,
'Trespassing':23,
'Family Offenses':22,
'Weapons Violations':21}

df = pd.DataFrame(list(data.items()), columns=['Crime', 'Count'])

base = alt.Chart(df, title='San Francisco Crime (11/05 - 11/11)').encode(
    x=alt.X('Count', axis=None),
    y=alt.Y('Crime', title='Crimes reported to SFPD, by top complaint', 
    sort=list(df.Crime.values)))

bars = base.mark_bar(size=22).encode(color=alt.condition(
    alt.datum.Count > 700,
    alt.value('#e17700'),
    alt.value('#00648e')))

text = alt.Chart(df).mark_text(
    color='white',
    align='left',
    x=3
).encode(alt.Text('Count:N'), alt.Y('Crime',   sort=list(df.Crime.values)))

chart = bars + text
chart.properties(width=700).configure_axisY(
    titleAngle=0, 
    titleY=-10,
    titleX=-60,
    labelPadding=160, 
    labelAlign='left'
)
```

[image]